# Error using subprocess with export ODBCINI in python?

Tags: python

I need to connect to a test server and run a sql query using pyodbc. For that I first need to set ODBCINI environment variable. I tried including that in python code using subprocess.

```
import subprocess
import pyodbc

bashCommand = "export ODBCINI=~/odbc.ini"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

pyodbc.pooling = False
conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='test',autocommit=True,ansi=True)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Below is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_si_web_impressions_bcookie_dealid.py", line 15, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='tdwb',autocommit=True,ansi=True)
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [DataDirect][ODBC lib] System information file not found. Please check the ODBCINI environment variable. (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I guess it implies that it din't export the ODBCINI variable so it couldn't connect to server. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work as you intend because a subprocess that is spawned can only affect it's own environment, and thus the one of the processes it spawns (as they inherit it).

So your bash-command is essentially a NOP.

Instead, you need to manipulate your own environment, by using os.environ:

```
 import os
 os.environ["ODBCINI"]="~/odbc.ini"
```

Then your connect should work.

Comment: I tried with this.
`#!/usr/bin/env python  

import pyodbc 
import os  
os.environ["ODBCINI"]="~/odbc.ini"  

pyodbc.pooling = False  
conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='test',autocommit=True,ansi=True)  
cur = conn.cursor()`   
Still same error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='test',autocommit=True,ansi=True)
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [DataDirect][ODBC lib] System information file not found. Please check the ODBCINI environment variable. (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Comment: It might be that you need to call os.expanduser on the argument. Or give it as full path, e.g. "/home/foobar/odbc.ini"

Comment: And the obvious question: does the file exist? Try putting a statment "assert os.path.exists(os.environ['ODBCINI'])" after the setting of the variable.

Comment: Yeah, file exists. If I run the command on shell it works. and `echo $ODBCINI` shows the file path but after running it through python script `echo $ODBCINI` returns empty string. I have tried giving absolute path also. Doesn't work

Comment: Does the assert I mention work? And I don't understand the "running through python-script". What happens if you export the ODBCINI *before* invoking python, not making the os.environ-manipultion within the script?

Comment: assert gives no output. I am putting the above code in a python script and running it using `python temp.py` . If I export the ODBCINI before invoking python, not making the os.environ-manipultion within the script, then it works properly but I wanted to automate that process so that I don't have to run it everytime separately.